# JQM Multi-page app slide panel with AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax, html, jquery-mobile, cordova

I am building a multi-page app, each of which has an identical slide panel. The links in the slide panel links to the other pages with data-ajax=false. Now I want to switch on data-ajax such that the page transition can be handled by jQM through AJAX (and remove the white annoying flicker during full reload of pages).

The structure of all the pages are mostly the same:

```
...
<body>
<div data-role="page"  text-align="center" > 
    <div class="panel" data-role="panel" id="panel-left">
        <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="./index.html">
                <p>Home</p>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="./page2.html">
                <p>Page 2</p>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="./page3.html">
                <p>Page 3</p>
            </a>
        </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="header" class="si-icons si-icons-default" data-role="header" data-position="fixed" data-tap-toggle="false">
         <a class="panel" href="#panel-left"><img title="menu" alt="menu" class="panel" src="./image/panel.png"></a>
         <h1>My PAGE</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="ui-panel-wrapper" data-role="content">
         ...
    </div>
</div>
</body>
...
```

**The problem:**

1. Where should I put the page-dependent JS? in the data-role="page" div?
2. The panel exists in the first page I opened, then I click in a link in the panel and I am directed to the other page. The panel in the second page is missing (i.e. a white panel). Why?

Comment: Use _external panel_, one panel for all pages.

Comment: @Omar right, i'm doing it right now but I have problems with all the `$(document).ready` js in the js files.

Comment: what problems do you have? you shouldn't be using `.ready()` in jQM.

Comment: So what should i be using?

Comment: page events ([pageContainer events](http://jqmtricks.wordpress.com/2014/03/26/jquery-mobile-page-events/)). If you have JS code, post it.